# Early Dark Energy

Tags: cosmology

Early dark energy is one of the possible solutions for the Hubble tension. If it is correct then wouldn't the universe be somewhat larger than our current best estimates?

early dark energy:https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.04492

Comment: Details please.  Why do you suppose this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "early dark energy". In a standard model, dark energy has always existed.

Comment: In what sense are you referring to the size of the universe?

Comment: current diameter or radius

Comment: Of what? The observable universe? The universe as a whole? (We don't have estimates for the latter, just lower limits.)